# AJAX data is not submitting to Laravel controller - Laravel 6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've set up two buttons which when clicked are just sending their values to my controller, then I am trying to send back AJAX HTML to show the users profile on the main page. I can't get the input `id` to make it to the controller no matter what I try.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="signup-li">
    @foreach($participants as $participant)
        <button type="submit" name="id" value="{{$participant->id}}">
            {{$participant->phone}}
        </button>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        console.log(id);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/get-profile/',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
            data: { "id" : id },
            success: function(data){
                console.log('hi');
            },

            error: function(xhr,textStatus,thrownError) {
                alert(xhr + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my controller function:

```
public function getProfile(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');
    Log::info($id);
    $participant = Participant::where('id','=',$id)->first();
    $returnHTML = view('ajax.user-profile')->with('participant', $participant)->renderSections()['content'];

    return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I try to log the request and nothing comes through. I have CSRF disabled for this route. The issue is that the participant is not found because the ID is not getting to the controller. Why isnt it making it?

Comment: Are you sure the `getProfile` method is actually called?

Comment: in my routes - 
Route::post('/get-profile', 'ParticipantController@getProfile');

Comment: Look at the browser's Developer console in the Network tab. You should see the HTTP request there along with a response from the server, which should tell you more.

Comment: Does your `console.log()` show the ID?  Is the button inside a `<form>`? If yes, you also need to `.preventDefault()` to stop the standard form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You may add `dataType: 'json'`, to your `$.ajax({...})` call